# Prove the limit fails to exist

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $f(x, y) = \frac{|x|}{|x| + y^2}$, for $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$. Show that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ doesn't exist.

Obviously, we let $y = mx$ then,

$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{|x| + (mx)^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{|x| + m^2|x| \cdot |x|}  = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1 + m^2\cdot|x|} = 1$$

This failed, so let $y = mx^2$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{|x| + m^2 |x| \cdot |x|^3} = 1$$

I keep getting $1$, so what do I do?

Comment: Note that $f(0,y) \neq f(x,0)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Comment: Along $x=0$, the limit is $0$.  Along $y=0$, the limit is $1$.

Comment: Maybe in the other way round...let $x=my^2$

Answer (score 0):

Take:

$$
y = \sqrt x
$$

I think it is useful in your approach to test the limit along a curve of the form:

$$
y = mx^p
$$

With arbitrary $p$ to see for which value(s) it cracks.